# Não consigo fazer o css funcionar no GitHub

Tags: css, github

Passei o repository pro GitHub e simplesmente o css parou de funcionar https://github.com/WinnySampaio/assets.git, esse é o projeto.
Sou iniciante!!

Comment: Sua pergunta carece de informação.

Comment: Nenhuma postagem pode depender de links externos. Se sua pergunta for útil para o [objetivo do site](/help), queira [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema. Ao editar, a postagem é destacada para reavaliação da comunidade (e mesmo que não venha a ser reaberta, esclarecendo o problema ao menos abre uma chance para alguma sugestão ser dada via comentários)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Tem dois erros em seu arquivo **index.html**:

Na linha 51 se tem uma tag `<div>` que está sendo aberta, porém ela não está sendo fechada. Falta a tag de fechamento `</div>` na linha 61.

```
<div class="dados">
   <p class="dados1">Species<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;Seed</span></p>   
   <p class="dados1">Height<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;2'3.6'(0,70 cm)</span></p>    
   <p class="dados1">Weight<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;15.2 lbs(6.9 kg)</span></p>    
   <p class="dados1">Abilities<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;overgrow, Chlorophyl</span></p>  
   <p class="dados2">Breeding</p>
   <p class="dados3">Gender<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;♂️ 87.5%&emsp;♀️ 12.5% </span></p>
   <p class="dados3">Eggs Groups<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;Monster</span></p>
   <p class="dados3">Eggs Cycle<span class="colorPreta">&emsp;Grass</span></p>
</div>
```

Sobre o **css** na linha 21 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/global.css">` a string do **href** está apontando pra uma pasta chamada **"/assets"**, porém não existe essa pasta em seu diretório. O correto deveria ser assim:

```
<!-- Nosso CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pokedex.css">
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).